# Flash messages to my logged-in browser users?

Tags: java, jsp, broadcast

I have to make an interface for ADMIN where the admin user can log in and `broadcast` a message to the users.

I want the message to be flashed on each users' browser so whoever is logged in will see it.

I don't want the page that the user views to require polling for a message. Is there a way by which this can be done **without the pages repeatedly making requests**?

The log of the users currently logged in are available in the database.

Comment: HTTP being stateless, I doubt if there is a way to truly push the messages to browser without using some polling technique from the browser client.

Comment: Do you want your message to be displayed immediately, or on the users' next request?

Comment: @f_puras I need them to be flashed Immediately...

Comment: This should be possible with WebSockets - if you can do without supporting IE...

Comment: try with Apache Tomcat Comet API....it may help you